# If y is a vector, what do y superscript + and y superscript - mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology

What are $y^+$ and $y^-$ supposed to represent?  $y$ is a vector.

Comment: Hard to say unless you give us some further context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As lhf points out, it depends on what context you are using these.

One possible answer which I have seen is $y^{+}$ is a vector whose elements are same as $y$ if the corresponding element in $y$ is positive and is zero if the corresponding element in $y$ is negative. Similarly, $y^{-}$ is a vector whose elements are same as $y$ if the corresponding element in $y$ is negative and is zero if the corresponding element in $y$ is positive.i.e.

If $y \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}$, then

$y^{+} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}$ with $y^{+}(i) = \max(y(i),0)$

and

$y^{-} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}$ with $y^{-}(i) = \min(y(i),0)$

Hence, $y(i) = y^{+}(i) + y^{-}(i)$

Comment: Thank you, this is it.  Sorry I didn't provide any context, but I'm too tired to type right now.

Comment: FWIW, the book I'm using seems to be defining $y^-$ the way you did but negated so $y^-$ is nonnegative.

Comment: @Matt: Yes. Some people use that convention as well i.e. $y^{-}(i) = \max(-y(i),0)$ so that both $y^{+}$ and $y^{-}$ are non-negative and then we get $y(i) = y^{+}(i) - y^{-}(i)$